# Smooth streaming via application

Tags: smooth-streaming

Can I use smooth streaming to load music and maybe a video on Android, iOS, Windows phone without using a browser? (Via application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in developing an application which will stream content from the internet, then you can use the [SmoothStreamingClient](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/smooth-streaming-client-sdk) for WindowsPhone. iOS should also support natively SmoothStreaming.

About Android I am not really sure.

Comment: I am not accustomed to the smooth because I want to use simple mp3 and then think about videos, and saw the smooth has some restrictions on the type of content pelomenos could not make it open only a simple mp3 videos of worked examples, and locally, client does not work remotely.

Comment: @LucasRodriguesSena well in that case, better start of using native player capabilities on each platform. SmoothStreaming really make sense only for videos streaming.

Comment: Okay thanks, IOS app is ready, compatible whit html5. But I will study about the Smooth, in future will be great usefully here.